# how to comment an idented line in a file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to comment a line within a .yml file through the command line, I am using this command `sudo sed -i '/<pattern_to_find>/s/^#//g' /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml` an it works fine as long as the line is not idented, but I am loking to change an idented line such as:

```
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  # host: "localhost:5601"

  # Kibana Space ID
```

any ideas how to achieve this? I cannot figure it out

Comment: Does the string `pattern_to_find` start with `^#`?  Add some whitespace to that pattern.  eg make it `^[ \t]*#` or similar.

Comment: The key detail is the content of `pattern_to_find`, and it defeats the purpose of your question to hide that value.

Comment: the string ```pattern_to_find``` is the line which says ```# host: "localhost:560!"``` so I tried with ```sudo sed -i '/localhost:5601/s/^#//g' /etc/metricbeat/metricbeat.yml ```

Comment: So add some whitespace before the `#`

Comment: hahaha thanks mate I was so frustrated I did not see how easy it was. I was trying to find some identation character or something like it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I strongly encourage you *not* use the `-i` option to `sed`, I will not discuss that beyond mentioning it here.  You just need to change your search pattern.  Try:

```
sed -E '/^( *)#( host: "localhost:560!")/s//\1 \2/'
```

This will fail to match hard tabs.  Depending on how much portability you want between different versions of said, that can be a pain to deal with.  But the following should work:

```
sed -E '/^([[:space:]]*)#( host: "localhost:560!")/s//\1 \2/'
```